# How do i divide numbers by two numbers without dividing with both of them?

Tags: python

need to solve this python question for my class pls help:

Write a program that prints out all the numbers from 1 to 100 that are divisible by 3 or 7 but not divisible by both.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
for i in range(1, 100+1):
   is_divide_by_both=False
   if(i%3==0):
      if(i%7==0):
        is_divide_by_both=True
   if  not is_divide_by_both:
     print(i)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
d3_and_d7 = []
d3_or_d7 = []

for i in range(1, 101):
    d3 = False
    d7 = False
    both = False
    if i%3 == 0: d3 = True
    if i%7 == 0: d7 = True
    if d3 and d7 :
        d3_and_d7.append(i)
        continue
    if d3 or d7:
        d3_or_d7.append(i)

print("Divisible by both: ", d3_and_d7)
print("Divisible by 3 or 7: ", d3_or_d7)
```